# Storing Integers in Android

Tags: java, android, integer

So I have 3 classes. I was trying things out and ended up making an Integers.xml file under values as to try and save my values. It works, but I cannot find out how to change it. I understand how to grab it using.

**res.getInteger(R.integer.int);**

I just can't seem to find out how to change it and I am starting to come to the conclusion that you cannot. I was wondering where would I need to store values so when I switch to and from my other classes that the integers don't all reset. I apologize because there is tons of storing data in Android, but I couldn't implement what they told me to my code. If there is just a simple way to make sure it just remembers 5 Integers I can finish my app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The values stored in your integers.xml are constants, so they cannot change. A quick way of storing 5 integers is by using `SharedPreferences` and storing each integer with its own unique key.
For example, in an activity:

```
SharedPreference prefs = getSharedPreferences("com.example.myapp", MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
editor.putInt("Integer1", 234);
editor.putInt("Integer2", 748);
editor.putInt("Integer3", 747);
editor.putInt("Integer4", 42);
editor.putInt("Integer5", 463);
```

To get the values back:

```
SharedPreference prefs = getSharedPreferences("com.example.myapp", MODE_PRIVATE);
int integer1 = prefs.getInt("Integer1", 0);
int integer2 = prefs.getInt("Integer2", 0);
int integer3 = prefs.getInt("Integer3", 0);
int integer4 = prefs.getInt("Integer4", 0);
int integer5 = prefs.getInt("Integer5", 0);
```

Comment: @TeenCoder I added an example

Comment: thank you very much! I came across this before the example, but hopefully people who came across this problem will have it solved as well.

Comment: how do I make sure it runs editor.putInt("Integer1", #) only once

Comment: @TeenCoder You can first get the integer by using the second block of code and if the integer is not equal to zero, write it in using the `putInt` method. That way, it will only be written once.

Comment: ok thank you, I thought if I were to try and get an int from a non existing integer it would give me an error.

Comment: @TeenCoder no, the second parameter in `prefs.getInt("Integer1", 0)` defines the value it will return if it doesn't exist. In this case, it will be `0`

Comment: Wait doesn't getInt return the integer? and putInt places it? *edit nvm I got it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110443/discussion-between-agileninja-and-teencoder).

Answer (score 1):

Here is the basic code to read and write to SharedPrefs. Note that this approach saves the data locally on the user's device:

Write:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
editor.putInt(getString(R.string.saved_high_score), newHighScore);
editor.commit();
```

Read:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
int defaultValue = getResources().getInteger(R.string.saved_high_score_default);
long highScore = sharedPref.getInt(getString(R.string.saved_high_score), defaultValue);
```

Source: [Official Google Documentation](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html)

Comment: thank you and everyone else who responded. I ended up looking at a youtube tutorial and was able to save my integers. This is 100x easier then the other data saving methods I came across.

Answer (score 0):

If you dont want to store those integers after you closed your app you cant put them to a static list like

```
public static List<Integer> integerList = new ArrayList<>();
```

If you want to store these integers permanently you can use the [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html)

or you can use an SQLite database like [this](https://github.com/hdani9307/WaterReminder/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/hoffmann/daniel/waterreminder/DatabaseAdapter.java)

Answer (score 0):

You're right, you **can't** edit the `resources` files, because they are ran only once.
If you want to store values that will stay in your app after it is closed, you can use `SharedPreferences`.
If you want to store values during runtime, you can create a class with `getters` and `setters` :

```
public class Values {

  int value1;
  int value2;

  public int getValue2() {
    return value2;
  }

  public void setValue2(int value2) {
    this.value2 = value2;
  }

  public int getValue1() {
    return value1;
  }

  public void setValue1(int value1) {
    this.value1 = value1;
  }
}
```

In any activity you can set and get you values like that :

```
Values.setValue1(yourValue1);
Values.getValue1();
```